# Swapping values found by regex with .replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to swap around two strings I found and stored in JavaScript:

```
searchPattern = new RegExp ("(this)\\D{0,2}(that)", "gi");

var groupOneMatches = [];
var groupTwoMatches = [];

var text = "this that test string this: that";

text = text.replace(searchPattern, function (match, $1, $2) {

groupOneMatches.push($1);
groupTwoMatches.push($2);

});

alert(text);
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Java. More like JavaScript. What is the exact problem?

Comment: `text = text.replace(...)`. ;)

Comment: Yes, JavaScrip, sorry. I am trying to swap, or change, the "this" and "that", stored in $1 and $2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace` will replace each match of the regex with a string determined by the second argument to `.replace`. If you want to insert new substrings to replace the old ones, that function needs to return a string. Something like this:

```
var searchPattern = new RegExp ("(this)(\\D{0,2})(that)", "gi");
var text = "this that test string this: that";
text = text.replace(searchPattern, function (match, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $3 + $2 + $1;
});
```

At least, I *think* this is what you wanted, but it's not very clear.

Comment: Yep, that does it. Figured you could do it without making a function too with just  `text = text.replace(searchPattern, "$3$2$1")`

Answer (score 0):

`text` will always show as the original string because you never set the new value for it:

```
text = text.replace(...)
```

Comment: Forgot to add that to the example, but it still swaps the matches for "undefined" when I do $1 = $2 or $2 = "SWAP TEST"